# swiftmailer sending email rejected in Silex

Tags: php, symfony, email, swiftmailer, silex

I've been trying to use swiftmailer with Silex, and after reading the complete documentation, looking at the topics here and making some tests, I have strictly no idea why the email doesn't want to be sent.
To look for an answer, I have been using the ArrayLogger plugin which gave me a hint : `<< 521 Mail rejected - not allowed to receive mail from this sender`.

Here is the Service declaration from my app.php :

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SwiftmailerServiceProvider());
```

Here is my controller :

```
/**
     * Contact page controller.
     *
     * @param Application $app Silex application
     */
    public function contactAction(Request $request, Application $app) {
        $contact = new Contact();
        $contactForm = $app['form.factory']->create(new ContactType(), $contact);
        $contactForm->handleRequest($request);
        if ($contactForm->isSubmitted() && $contactForm->isValid()) {
            $contact->notify($app);
            $app['session']->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'Your message was successfully sent.');
        }
        return $app['twig']->render('contact.html.twig', array(
            'contactForm' => $contactForm->createView()));
    }
```

And here is the method notify from the Contact class :

```
/**
     * Sends an email to the administrator using this object's parameters
     * 
     * @param Application $app
     */
    public function notify($app) {
        $transport = \Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.numericable.fr', 25);

        $mailer = \Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

        // To use the ArrayLogger
        $logger = new \Swift_Plugins_Loggers_ArrayLogger();
        $mailer->registerPlugin(new \Swift_Plugins_LoggerPlugin($logger));

        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance($this->getEmitter().' wants to help')
        ->setFrom(array($this->getEmail()))
        ->setTo(array('example@rabbit.com'))
        ->setBody($this->getMessage());

        $app['swiftmailer.use_spool'] = false;
        if (!$mailer->send($message, $failures)) {
            var_dump($logger->dump());
        }
    }
```

The configuration (email and port) are informations I found in my file php.ini but as I don't have much knowledge in all this, I might have been mistaken there.

Comment: Can you send email to other domains/addresses using this?. [SMTP error code 521 means that the email server you sent to doesn't accept incoming emails](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1846.txt).

Comment: No. I tried any other combination of emails and I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be a mail relay server problem, not a SwiftMailer problem. Check that you are allowed to send emails using this server using telnet. Have a look at here if you don't know how to do that :
http://ubuntuwiki.net/index.php/SMTP,_testing_via_Telnet

Comment: Connection to localhost... Impossible to open a connexion for the host, on the port 25: Failure on connection , I tried also with the ports 587 and 8080 but I get the same error.

Comment: @Cachwir You don't have to telenet localhost, localhost is your own machine. From the server where this PHP is executed you have to telnet the SMTP server in your case smtp.numericable.fr, so your command must be ```telnet smtp.numericable.fr 25``` and then follow the link instructions. I repeat that you must do that from the server where your PHP code is executed not from your own development computer.

Comment: @mTorres It doesn't work. Here is the log : 220 smtp2.josinet.cz ready
HELO justtesting250 Welcome 10.63.2.20
MAIL FROM : me@telnettingin.com250 me Sender Ok
RCPT TO : postmaster@mail.getsdeliveredhere.net521 Mail rejected - not allowed to receive mail from this sender

Comment: The error message means that `postmaster@mail.getsdeliveredhere.net` doesn't allow messages from `me@telnettingin.com`. Sounds like a configuration mistake.

Comment: @Cachwir, you just probably need some SMTP authentication. Notice that as soon as you instruct the server that you want to send a mail (rcpt to) the server rejects the command. Do you have a username and password? If so, [try to use them when creating the new instance](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html#smtp-with-a-username-and-password)

Comment: I don't know. I didn't see any in the php.ini file.

Comment: If your are using Numericable, you need authentication for the SMTP, take a look at the configuration here : https://assistance.numericable.fr/Les-adresses-de-serveur-de-messagerie-Numericable.html

Comment: So which SMTP are you using ?

Comment: Actually, I am not using Numericable anymore and where I am, I am not the owner of the connection.

Comment: I don't know right now and I don't think I would be able to figure it out. Maybe it would be better for me to test it on an online server.

Comment: Okay, for future debug, I would suggest you to check if your SMTP needs authentication, I think this is the problem.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that when I'm back in France. Thank you very much, Raphaël. :)